# How to fix "undefined reference" compilation error cause by QObject ineherited Class in new QT

Tags: c++, qt, qobject

I need a **signal emitter class** which will be connected with a slot.

But facing some compilation error. Already tried many fixes from Internet.

**Basic Class Structure:**

```
class emiterClass:public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT;
signals:
    void testSignal();
public:
    emiterClass();
    ~emiterClass();

    void signalEmiter();
};
```

**The Error**
[Error showed in Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mUFA.png)
Also in Text:

```
/usr/bin/ld: main.o: in function `emitterClass::emitSignal()':
/mnt/Data/Documents/DevP/QT/build-terminalhelp-Desktop-Debug/../terminalhelp/main.cpp:25: undefined reference to `emitterClass::testSignal()'
/usr/bin/ld: main.o: in function `main':
/mnt/Data/Documents/DevP/QT/build-terminalhelp-Desktop-Debug/../terminalhelp/main.cpp:45: undefined reference to `emitterClass::emitterClass()'
/usr/bin/ld: /mnt/Data/Documents/DevP/QT/build-terminalhelp-Desktop-Debug/../terminalhelp/main.cpp:45: undefined reference to `emitterClass::~emitterClass()'
/usr/bin/ld: /mnt/Data/Documents/DevP/QT/build-terminalhelp-Desktop-Debug/../terminalhelp/main.cpp:45: undefined reference to `emitterClass::~emitterClass()'
/usr/bin/ld: main.o: in function `responseClass::responseClass()':
/mnt/Data/Documents/DevP/QT/build-terminalhelp-Desktop-Debug/../terminalhelp/main.cpp:30: undefined reference to `vtable for responseClass'
/usr/bin/ld: main.o: in function `responseClass::~responseClass()':
/mnt/Data/Documents/DevP/QT/build-terminalhelp-Desktop-Debug/../terminalhelp/main.cpp:30: undefined reference to `vtable for responseClass'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:299: terminalhelp] Error 1
06:24:35: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project terminalhelp (kit: Desktop)
When executing step "Make"
```

**My System:**

Installed Version: Qt 5.14.2

OS : Manjrao Linux

IDE: QT Creator 4.12.4

**Full Source Code**

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QtConcurrent/QtConcurrent>

class emitterClass:public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT;
signals:
    void testSignal();
public:
    emitterClass();
    ~emitterClass();

    void emitSignal();
};


void emitterClass::emitSignal()
{
    while(1)
    {
        system("sleep 1"); //Sleeps for a second
        emit testSignal();
        qDebug()<<"Signal Emited\n";
    }
}

class responseClass:public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public slots:
    void testSlot()
    {
        qDebug()<<"Signal Recieved\n";
    }
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    emitterClass ec;
    responseClass rc;

    QObject::connect(&ec, SIGNAL(testSignal()),
                     &rc, SLOT(testSlot()));
    ec.emitSignal();
    
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: add `#include "main.moc"`

Comment: No such file directory eror is shown If I include "main.moc".. Though this article solved the issue. I was suggested by StackOverflow...
ttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/46926982/nothing-helped-to-solve-undefined-reference-to-vtable-in-qt

Comment: You have to do the following: 1) Delete the build folder, 2) press the "Run qmake" option from the "Build" menu (that generates the main.moc file), and 3) Then press the "run" button.